# Confusion regarding the definition of Fermi's Golden rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, fermis-golden-rule

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule), the definition starts in the following way:

> "In quantum physics, Fermi's golden rule is a formula that describes the transition rate (the probability of a transition per unit time) from one energy eigenstate of a quantum system to a group of energy eigenstates in a continuum, as a result of a weak perturbation. "

Why is the transition rate the probability of transition per unit of time and not simply, the nr. of transitions per unit of time?

Comment: It depends on the understanding of "experiment". If we apply the usual framework of quantum mechanics of "preparation, evolution, measurement" for every single one of an infinite number of independent members of a quantum mechanical ensemble, then we get a probability. If we do a real benchtop measurement (e.g. in nuclear physics) with many atoms, then we will get an average frequency which is proportional to the number of atoms in the original exited state. A radioactive decay would be an example of such a scenario. Is that what you mean? How we translate between theory and experiment?

Comment: I mean, the definition of transition rate is unclear to me. Rate, implies a repeated event (if one can say so) per unit of time. Now, transition rate, the way I see it, is the nr. of transitions per unit of time. But there it's the probability of transition per unit of time. Perhaps, if I dumb it down, if you have N particles from which N1 transit to another state at a moment in time, you can measure the probability  of transition. In another moment of time, from N particles N2 transit, which corresponds to a different probability of transition for this other moment of time.

Comment: Hence probability of transition per unit of time. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: If the probability of transition of one particle is p, for a collection of N particles, the rate of transition is pN, all in the same time interval. Ignore the final state options hinted at.

Comment: I think the disconnect comes from the fact that in non-relativistic QM we are looking at infinite copies of the system but characterize everything for only one copy at a time. That's what we normalize the wave function to and hence we get a transition probability (per time interval). In an experiment we are looking at many (independent!) copies at the same time and what we are measuring is an average frequency, just like Cosmos Zachos said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it applies to a single initial state, from whence the number of transitions per unit time for an ensemble of initial states can be derived.